# C printf causes errors on all lines below it

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

Ok, I've been programming in C++ for a little while now, and I am trying to help a friend with his assignments that are done in C. After looking at how to do some things in C that differ from C++, I began to help my friend make a simple program that will print something to the console and then read what the user inputs. We have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define  WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str1[] = "Please enter your name.";
    printf(str1); // This appears to be the nuisance line.

    char buffer[64];
    fgets(buffer, 64, stdin);

    printf("Your name is %s", buffer);   
    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, now here is the bizarre thing. I get the following errors in the console while trying to compile this.

```
1>c:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\c++\credit2\credit2\main.c(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>c:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\c++\credit2\credit2\main.c(13): error C2065: 'buffer' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\c++\credit2\credit2\main.c(13): warning C4047: 'function' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
1>c:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\c++\credit2\credit2\main.c(13): warning C4024: 'fgets' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
1>c:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\c++\credit2\credit2\main.c(15): error C2065: 'buffer' : undeclared identifier
```

However, if I remove all code **below** the printf statement, the program will compile and run perfectly. If I take out the printf statement, the program will compile and run perfectly. Just to see how odd this error is, I changed the code to this to see what would happen when I compile it:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str1[] = "Please enter your name.";
    printf(str1); // This appears to be the nuisance line.

    int x = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when compiling this...

```
1>c:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\c++\credit2\credit2\main.c(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
```

I decided to look at other people's C programs that use printf, and it does not appear I am doing anything wrong at all. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and I think it's the problem here. I may not use C, but I know the original code is perfectly valid C++ code (I compiled it as C++ code and it compiled and ran fine), and it appears to be perfectly valid C code. Something funky is going on with that printf statement. Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: Microsoft C, coding like it's 1989. I wonder why they don't bother to fix this.

Comment: @CharlieBurns file a connect bug?  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: @EdwardThomson, nah, I get a chuckle out of watching the dumb crap Microsoft does. Since I don't have to use it, it's entertainment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `printf` is not the problem.  MSVC versions prior to 12.0 (aka "Visual Studio 2013") require that you declare your variables C89 style, at the top of the block, before any statements.  **(C is not C++).**  Eg:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str1[] = "Please enter your name.";
    char buffer[64];

    printf(str1);

    fgets(buffer, 64, stdin);

    printf("Your name is %s", buffer);   
    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can do this in any block, it need not be the beginning of a function.  If declaring every variable at the top of the function is particularly loathesome to you, you can sprinkle magic braces throughout for new blocks:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str1[] = "Please enter your name.";
    printf(str1);

    {
        /* This block is unnecessary, but allows us to declare buffer here */
        char buffer[64];
        fgets(buffer, 64, stdin);

        printf("Your name is %s", buffer);   
    }

    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Though this may become a case of which you hate less.  (For me, it's almost always less awful to put them at the top of the function.)

Thankfully, beginning with MSVC 12.0, the Microsoft compiler team has made a new investment in their C compiler and believes that C99 might be worth implementing after all.  This is a wonderful new development, in contrast to [previous decisions](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/485416/support-c99).

Thus, beginning with MSVC 12.0, **inline declaration of variables is supported!**  However, if you are stuck on previous versions of MSVC or Visual Studio, or if you need to interoperate with those who are, you will have to stick with declaring your variables at the top of a block.

Comment: Well that's...odd to me, as someone who has never touched C code and has only done C++ for a while now. Is that a limitation of the language, or is that just a requirement of the Visual Studio compiler?

Comment: @NkosiDean: it's a C89 language limitation.  That MSVC doesn't support anything newer is their fault.

Comment: I usually declare the majority of my variables at the top of functions anyway, but as someone who has only programmed in C++, C#, Java, and a little bit of Python and Javascript (So only high level languages), that just seems like odd to me. It still makes sense though, a limitation like having to have functions defined in the same file forward declared or defined above each other in order to be called by each other. Well thank you for the information, this knowledge should save me a lot of headaches if I ever need to write anything in C.